# how to move files with the exact same name of the xml file to another directory in pyhon

Tags: python

hi I have the following code that works just fine but I do not know how to move the matching name files to the same directory. for example I have 3 files with the same name (xml, jpeg, txt) when I move the xml file I want all the files with the same name to move with it. I was looking in the forum and did not find anything.

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def contains_drone(path):
 tree = ET.parse(path.as_posix())
 root = tree.getroot()
 for obj in root.findall('object'):
    rank = obj.find('name').text
    if rank == 'car':           
         return True
 return False


def move_drone_files(src="D:\\TomProject\\Images\\", 
dst="D:\\TomProject\\Done"):
 src, dst = Path(src), Path(dst)
 for path in src.iterdir():
    if path.suffix == '.xml' and contains_drone(path):
        print(f'Moving {path.as_posix()} to {dst.as_posix()}')
        shutil.move(path, dst)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    move_drone_files()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the meaning of run 2 function? Do you mean concurrently? Are you able to call `move_drone_files()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


 def contains_drone(path):
    tree = ET.parse(path.as_posix())
    root = tree.getroot()
    for obj in root.findall('object'):
        rank = obj.find('name').text
        if rank == 'drone':           
             return True
    return False
    

def move_drone_files(src='D:\\TomProject\\Images', dst='D:\\TomProject\\Images\\Done'):
    src, dst = Path(src), Path(dst)
    for path in src.iterdir():
       if path.suffix == '.xml' and contains_drone(path):
           print(f'Moving {path.as_posix()} to {dst.as_posix()}')
           shutil.move(path, dst)

if __name__=='__main__':
    move_drone_files()
```

Then simply execute your file with `python3 file.py` and the code in `main` will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `if __name__ == "__main__":` at the end of the file, with the function you want to call:

```py
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def contains_drone(path):
    tree = ET.parse(path.as_posix())
    root = tree.getroot()
    for obj in root.findall('object'):
        rank = obj.find('name').text
        if rank == 'drone':           
             return True
    return False
    

def move_drone_files(src='D:\\TomProject\\Images', dst='D:\\TomProject\\Images\\Done'):
    src, dst = Path(src), Path(dst)
    for path in src.iterdir():
       if path.suffix == '.xml' and contains_drone(path):
           print(f'Moving {path.as_posix()} to {dst.as_posix()}')
           shutil.move(path, dst)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    move_drone_files()
```

In your code, `move_drone_files()` is calling `contains_drone(path)` inside itself (see line `if path.suffix == '.xml' and contains_drone(path):`), so it seems that you only need to call `move_drone_files()` in the main section. Then you just need to execute the python script with a cmd like: `python script.py`, `python3 script.py` or `python3.X script.py` depending on which python version you installed.

PD: I fixed some typos and tab errors you had in the code you posted

Comment: looks good for me now but i have an error at the shutil line that says :AttributeError("'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'rstrip'",)

Comment: [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) _"accepts a path-like object for both src and dst"_ from Python 3.9 upwards. So if you're running a version below 3.9 this won't work.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't _need_ the `if __name__ == "__main__":` to call a function.

Comment: im running in python 3.10 and it still doesnt work for me

Comment: i managed to run it now but i think it stops after the print line, it prints the files that moving to another directory but actually it doesnt move anything

Comment: thank you! I managed to make it! it works perfectly now! i edited the question now maybe can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a syntax error in your code: replace `src='D:\\TomProject\\Images, dst='D:\\TomProject\\Images\\Done'` with `src="D:\\TomProject\\Images", dst="D:\\TomProject\\Images\\Done"`.

Furthermore, remove the four spaces in front of `def move_drone_files(...)`, otherwise python will throw a syntax error.

To call one of these functions, you must type:

```py
containsdrone('path/to/file')
# and
move_drone_files()
```

The modified code should look like this:

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def contains_drone(path):
    tree = ET.parse(path.as_posix())
    root = tree.getroot()
    for obj in root.findall('object'):
        rank = obj.find('name').text
        if rank == 'drone':           
             return True
    return False
    

def move_drone_files(src="D:\\TomProject\\Images", dst="D:\\TomProject\\Images\\Done"):
    src, dst = Path(src), Path(dst)
    for path in src.iterdir():
       if path.suffix == '.xml' and contains_drone(path):
           print(f'Moving {path.as_posix()} to {dst.as_posix()}')
           shutil.move(path, dst)


containsdrone('path/to/file')
move_drone_files()
```

Comment: Nerver mind! Please just mark this answer as accepted